# Jest testing pub/sub

Tags: javascript, jquery, jestjs

I'm trying to test a pub/sub using jest.js but i'm getting an fail.
If I call the function directly the spy works. 
Do I need to mock my publish or is it ok to leave it the way it is.

```
  expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()
  Expected mock function to have been called.
```

Here is my test code.

```
    // jest.dontMock('create/user-input');
    import userInput from 'create/user-input';
    jest.dontMock('create/payment-type-display');
    import paymentTypeDisplay from 'create/payment-type-display';
    jest.dontMock('shared/broadcaster');
    import {subscribe, publish} from 'shared/broadcaster';  

    test('dispatch pageHandler', ()=>{
        const spy = jest.spyOn(userInput, 'pageHandler');
        publish('DISPLAY_UPDATE', $('#verify_view') );
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

    });
```

**UserImput.js**

```
class UserInput extends FieldApplicator{

    constructor( filter ) {
        super( filter ); // Inject Filters from ../create/display-filters
        this.pageHandler = this.pageHandler.bind(this);
        // Listen for broadcast from page-pagination :: displayViewById method.
        subscribe('DISPLAY_UPDATE', this.pageHandler);
    }

    // output results from FORM view to page. example data for (step3 & step 4)
    pageHandler( page ){
        super.output( page, this.result() );
    }

    result(){
        return formData.data( super.fieldNames() );
    }
}

let userInput = new UserInput( filter );

export default userInput;
```

Comment: Anyone able to help with this ???